# Question about Typescript optional objects in interface

Tags: typescript, types

I am facing some issues with Typescript?

Suppose I have two interfaces defined, the second interface will use the first one as a type for its optional property of "link"

```
interface Link {
  href: string;
  text: string;
}

interface Container {
  id: number;
  link?: Link;
}
```

That is how I have it set up, however when I try to de-structure an Object that has the Container type

```
const {
  link:{
    href,
    text
   }
} = varOfTypeContainer
```

I get TypeScript warnings under both href and link
which state

> "Property 'href' does not exist on type 'Link | undefined'."

> "Property 'link' does not exist on type 'Link | undefined'."

How Could I fix this ?

Comment: The message is pretty clear: if your variable is a `Container`, how can you be sure there is a defined `link`  property to destructure? In `link` is not defined, what do you want to get in `href` and `text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `link` is optional it means it could be `undefined`, and thus not holding `href` or `text`.

You need to discard that possibility before, then the compiler will know and will allow you to de-structure:

```
if(varOfTypeContainer.link !== undefined){
  const {
    link:{
      href,
      text
     }
  } = varOfTypeContainer;
  // ...
}
```